# How to prevent parent element from executing click code when checkbox is clicked in SvelteJS?

Tags: svelte

## Problem

In a SvelteJS project, I have a parent component that executes its own click code when the user clicks on it.

I also have a child component that is an `<input>` element of `type="checkbox"`.

When the user clicks on the checkbox, the parent element executes its own click code as well.

However, I want the parent element to ignore this event and not execute its own click code when the checkbox is clicked. I tried using preventDefault but it didn't work.

*How can I achieve this in SvelteJS?* (in my case SvelteKit but is the same)

## Example Code

```html
<!-- Parent Component -->
<div on:click={parentClickHandler}>
  <Child />
</div>

<!-- Child Component -->
<input type="checkbox" on:click={childClickHandler}>
```

In the code above, when the user clicks on the `Child` component (which is an input element of type checkbox), both the `childClickHandler` and the `parentClickHandler` are executed.

I tried using `preventDefault` in the `childClickHandler` but it didn't work (it makes the things worse).

*How can I prevent the parentClickHandler from executing when the checkbox is clicked?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to stop the event from [propagating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). The simplest way of doing this with Svelte is simply to add the appropriate [event modifier](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/event-modifiers):

```
<input type="checkbox" on:click|stopPropagation={childClickHandler}>
```